# My app is free to download but has IAP, should I set it to free or paid on Google Developer Console?

Tags: google-developers-console

I'm getting the following message on Google Developer Console:

> Setting the price to 'Free' is permanent. You cannot change it back to
>   'Paid' again after publishing.

so I would like to make the right choice. If I want my app to be free for downloading but to have IAP once downloaded, should I set it to free or paid?

If you can, could you provide me a quote from the Google documentation answering to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be set to free. The paid-app option should be chosen if you charge a fee before the app install. All in-app purchases can be done in free apps as well.